# Configure VsCode Include Path for Protobuf installed with gRPC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using VsCode. I have gprc natively installed in the directory `/grpc`. I used their [quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/#setup) guide I have all the grpc header files needed; however, I cannot find all the files for protobuf. Within grpc I notice there is a `/thirdparty/protobuf` folder that I try to include but some artifacts are not found.

To note it compiles and runs perfectly. I am just setting up the include settings for c_cpp_properties.json for vscode linter.

Here is what I have

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",                      
                "${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/grpc",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/protos",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib**",
                "/grpc/include",
                "/grpc/third_party",
                "/grpc/third_party/protobuf"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu18",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My protobufs cannot files such as the following for the generated protobuf files.

```
#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
#include <google/protobuf/port_undef.inc>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/arena.h>
#include <google/protobuf/arenastring.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h>
#include <google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h>
#include <google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h>
#include <google/protobuf/message.h>
#include <google/protobuf/repeated_field.h>  // IWYU pragma: export
#include <google/protobuf/extension_set.h>  // IWYU pragma: export
#include <google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h>
#include <google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h>
```

[image: Issue finding protobuf headers]

Another screenshot to sanity check that grpc includes from `/grpc/includes` are properly recognized by vscode.

[image: No issue to grpc headers]

**Update**
Download [protobuf source file from github](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) then include the path below in the json settings file.

```
"/protobuf/src/google/protobuf"
```

Comment: So though grpc installs everything I need to download protobuf sources from their github https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf. I extracted them to my root at `/protobuf` then included the headers to the path `"/protobuf/src/google/protobuf"` in  c_cpp_properties.json file